# invalid date when using knockout.js and moment.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, momentjs

I'm using Knockout in combination with moment.js and C#.
In C# i pass in a ISO formatted date by using:
    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataObject}, new IsoDateTimeConverter());

In my HTML file i'm doing the following to display my date in a formatted way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var viewModel = {};
$.getJSON("http://www.test.com/jsonfile.txt", function(data) { 
viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
</script>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Time: <span data-bind="text: moment(model.Time).format('L')"></span></div>
```

I always get Invalid date but when i use:

```
<div>Time: <span data-bind="text: model.Time"></span></div>
```

it just displays correctly Time: 2014-08-25T09:49:00

Anyone an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? Or jQuery? Please tag *appropriately*. I've removed the irrelevant tags.

Comment: object has been serialized to json by using " JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataObject}, new IsoDateTimeConverter());"
There are multiple ways, that's why i added C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`fromJS`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) creates [*observables*](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html), so `model.Time` is a function. So:

```
<span data-bind="text: moment(model.Time()).format('L')"></span>
<!-- Change is here --------------------^^                   -->
```

But the KO way would probably be to create a computed observable for that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var viewModel = {};
$.getJSON("http://www.test.com/jsonfile.txt", function(data) { 
    viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    viewModel.model.FormattedTime = ko.computed(function() {
        return moment(viewModel.model.Time()).format('L');
    });
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
</script>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Time: <span data-bind="text: model.FormattedTime"></span></div>
```

Or better yet, your own binding: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/hunag/1)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.formattedTime = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    $(element).text(moment(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())).format('L'));
  }
};
```

Then:

```
<div>Time: <span data-bind="formattedTime: model.Time"></span></div>
```